# Circular step indicator step name position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm building step indicator for my form.
I found nice example on codepen and I'm trying to customize it to my needs.

HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="circle done">
        <span class="label">1</span>
        <span class="title">Order informations</span>
    </div>

    <span class="bar done"></span>

    <div class="circle">
        <span class="label">4</span>
        <span class="title">Order review</span>
    </div>

    <span class="bar"></span>

    <div class="circle">
        <span class="label">5</span>
        <span class="title">Finish</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */
 .progress {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle, .progress .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    top: -16px;
}
.progress .circle .label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
/* Done / Active */
 .progress .bar.done, .progress .circle.done {
    background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8bc435;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
    color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #0c95be;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
    color: #0c95be;
}
```

If I have single word as step description everything is aligned correctly, but if I have two words I get this result:

[image]

here is code snippet showing my result:

```js
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  i++;
  if (i == 8) {
    $('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
    $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
    i = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

.progress {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: -16px;
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="progress">

  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar half"></span>

  <div class="circle active">
    <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Review</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order informations</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Order review</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is jsfiddle with same code: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/40udkfov/3/

I need to fix text alignment, ideally text would be centered below circles one word per line.

**UPDATE:**

Here is image showing current result and expected:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/40udkfov/9/

**UPDATE 2**

Final version based on @dippas greate answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/40udkfov/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>Just add to your `.progress .circle .title` a `white-space:pre` and to have space between words increase `width` here `.progress .bar` from `80px` to `100px` or whatever you prefer.
See snippet below</del>

```js
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  i++;
  if (i == 8) {
    $('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
    $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
    i = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

.progress {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: -16px;
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  white-space:pre;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="progress">

  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar half"></span>

  <div class="circle active">
    <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Review</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done">
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order informations</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Order review</span>
  </div>

  <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle">
    <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** based on comments to answer:

added: `display:block` and changed your `line-height:30px` to `line-height:18px` in your`.progress .circle .title`

changed your `top:-16px` to `top:16px` in your `.progress .bar`.

added `vertical-align:top` to your `.progress .circle,.progress .bar`

remember that `inline-block` is by default `vertical-align:baseline`.

```js
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');
  i++;
  if (i == 8) {
    $('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
    $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
    i = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

.progress {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top:16px;

}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin:10px 0 0 -5px;
  display: block
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>

  </div> <span class="bar half"></span>

  <div class="circle active"> <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>

  </div> <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle"> <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Review</span>

  </div> <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle"> <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order informations</span>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle"> <span class="label">4</span>
    <span class="title">Order review</span>

  </div> <span class="bar"></span>

  <div class="circle"> <span class="label">5</span>
    <span class="title">Finish</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to center text below circles? right now they are aligned left.

Comment: They were already aligned left in your snippet so I guess my answer is correct right? I tried to align my snippet center but I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: One more thing: Can text be splitted into separate lines? Your solution is nice, but as I asked in question (last sentence) ideally I would like to have one word per line

Comment: Sorry I misread your last line. But from my tests the Issue is caused by having 2 lines as you mentioned. and you probably have to change a few more things including HTML markup to make this work as you intended.

Comment: I don't mind changing markup :) I know I can align every title separately, but I'll use progress in multiple places, so I'd like it to align itself.

Comment: Now lines in top and bottom progressbar are not aligned. Progress bar with 5 steps has line moved to top and second progress bar (with 3 steps) has line moved to bottom.

Comment: Nice work :) i just edited my question with more details. I think that image will be better than my poor English. I'd like text to move to second line if it won't fit in box, so "Order informations" would be in two lines, "step 2" in one and "Something really looong" in 3. Is this possible?

Comment: I added width to title and changed margin left a bit, so now it aligns better, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/40udkfov/11/ If You have other ideas how to improve it please write. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68891/discussion-between-dippas-and-misiu).